# Different response based on browser

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redis

I'm getting a strange behavior in my stack that I don't know where to look.
Using WordOps default install on Ubuntu 18.04, running on a VM Instance on GCP.
WordOps installed Nginx, php-fpm, MariaDB, WP and Redis cache out-of-the-box.

Initially, everything worked just fine. Then, on my phone, I started getting nginx 404, but on my pc it works. Sometimes the initial page doesn't work, but if I go to wp-admin, the page loads normally.

It is more strange that, on some devices, it works, it others it doenst, returning 404 page.

I really don't know know what's going on.

Anyway, the URL is www.lindastore.co.jp

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Let's Encrypt SSL certificates. Not sure why, but clearing then re-issuing fixed the problem.